# How do you delete the space between (, the var, and the other )?

Tags: python

**my code:**

```
import math

var = float(input())
SqrtVar = math.sqrt(var)
print("sqrt(", var, ") =", SqrtVar)
```

this prints out for input 5:

```
sqrt( var ) = *something or other*
how to remove the spaces after and before the var??
```

Comment: `print(f'sqrt({var}) = {SqrtVar}')`

Comment: pass a single string argument to print() using one of the two forms of variable insertion:  ```print("sqrt(%s) = %s' % (var, SqrtVar))```   or the f-string syntax ```print(f'sqrt({var}) = {SqrtVar}')```

Comment: thank you coders it's very appreciated and my problem is solved